# how to use pushViewController in ReaderSample of ZBarReader project

Tags: iphone, ios

I am working on the ReaderSample of ZBarReader  project,instead of use

> [self presentModalViewController: controller animated: YES];

I am trying to use

> [self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];

and when I run the application, there is nothing happens at all

I am wondering why I cant use **pushViewController**

Please advice me on this issue.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

The underlying reason is that apple does not allow stacking of navigation bars and UIImagePickerController has one of its own so than you will have two and will be confused..

The ZBarReader uses UIImagePickerController as its base class (not actually but internally somewhere ) and as you might be knowing you can't push a UIImagePickerController object on a navigation controller... that's why you have to use presentModalViewController

(Modal view controllers are used to tell the user that something important is happening apart from the normal app usage and clicking a picture is a part of that.. . its in the HIG)...

hoping this helps..